# Zero data written using python xlsxwriter function

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I am running some analysis on a dataset and have created some detail I want to output into a Excel workbook.

I have been trying to use the Openpyxl project module xlsxwriter within Pandas. from a MAC to QNap NAS storage. The reason to use this module is so I can add formatting to the output to enhance my presentation of the content.

I am finding an issue I do not understand and could do with some help.

This code works and creates an excel workbook that has a physical size and opens to the intended data.

```
df.to_excel('//Volumes/Data/Projectfolder/report.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

This code however while it processes and produces a file. The file that is created has zero bytes in size and can not be opened.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('//Volumes/Data/Projectfolder/report.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='report data', index=False)
```

This example has been followed from the xlsxwriter documentation for use in Pandas

My understanding is that I need to create the writer object so I can access the workbook and worksheets objects formatting is subsequently applied to. So while I can get the data out of Pandas and into a workbook via the first code route I'd like to understand why I can not follow the given example of creating the writer object.

all answers greatly appreciated.

Thanks Duncan

Comment: please produce a [mre], looks like the dataframe calling `to_excel` might be empty or the pointer for the file might be corrupted or trying to write an open file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs of [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) :

> The writer **should be used as a context manager**. Otherwise, call
> `close()` to save and close any opened file handles.
>
> *Source* : [[docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)]

So, either use a context manager (*..and it is a good habit to do that*) :

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('//Volumes/Data/Projectfolder/report.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer :
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='report data', index=False)
```

Or close the writer after saving the spreadsheet :

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('//Volumes/Data/Projectfolder/report.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='report data', index=False)
writer.close()
```